# Intersection of two congruent spirals

Tags: geometry

Let $S_1$ and $S_2$ be two congruent circular spirals in $\mathbb{R}^3$,
both with their axes passing through the origin. They are congruent in that their
radii are equal, as are their winding frequencies; but aside from being constrained
to have their axes through the origin, one is an arbitrary rigid reconfiguration of the other.

My question is: Do they always intersect,
and if so, where? It appears that they always intersect in two points, as in the example
below (origin: green), but I am not seeing a proof. Any help would be appreciated.

 [image: SpiralsIntersecting]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they don't have to intersect and generally will not.

Each helix lives on a circular cylinder, so if they intersect at all, it must be somewhere on the two orthogonal ellipses where the *cylinders* intersect. But each helix meets those ellipses only in finitely many points, so if you have a configuration where the helices do intersect, turning one of them by an infinitesimal amount will make it miss the point of intersection *without* thereby hitting any of the other possible intersection points.

---

Intuitively, if the winding period is much larger than the radii, then one certainly won't expect any intersection.

Comment: Thanks, Henning, especially for the intuitive explanation!

Answer (score 2):

My intuition says they usually do not intersect-they are both 1D curves, so a slight perturbation will make them miss.  Let's try two in a special position.  One is along $z$, following $x= \cos (z), y=\sin (z)$, with radius $1$ and pitch $2 \pi $.  The other is along $x$, following $y=\sin (bx+c), z=-\cos (bx+c)$, with radius 1, pitch $2 \pi/b$ and clocking $c$  Looking for intersections, we have $bx+c=z, x=-z=\cos z$.  This has only one solution for $z$, which is about $-0.739$  By selecting $b,c$ correctly, I can make the $x$ part fail easily.  So in this case we get at most one intersection, usually none.

Added:  note that the factor $b$ makes the helices non-congruent.  Following the title, we should set $b=1$

Comment: Thank you Ross; your reasoning is clear! And Yes, I meant for the spirals to be congruent, so $b$ should not be a variable that can be set.